# Ember App Kit and testing model hook

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-app-kit

In Ember App Kit, there are a number of testing examples that ship with the initial repo. One of those is a basic Route Unit test. This test is trivial, if the data is hard-coded in the model hook, like this:

```
test("#model", function(){
  deepEqual(route.model(), ['red', 'yellow', 'blue']);
});
```

How do you use the isolated container to test the model hook if it returns a promise from ember-data?

Here's the test:

```
import Activities from 'appkit/routes/activities';

var route;
module("Unit - ActivitiesRoute", {
  setup: function(){
    var container = isolatedContainer([
      'route:activities'
    ]);

    route = container.lookup('route:activities');
  }
});

test("#model", function(){
  deepEqual(route.model(), ['activity', 'activity2', 'activity3']);
});
```

And the actual Route's model hook:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.get('store').find('activity');
  }
});
```

### UPDATE:

After implementing the different approaches below from kingpin2k. Here is a summary of the outcomes.

**First approach:** works great ... yet no promise.

**Second approach:** returns the promise object (appears to be resolved), but the array, and correct values are assigned to _detail property.

```
test("#model", function(){
  deepEqual(route.model()['_detail'], ['activity', 'activity2', 'activity3']); //passes
});
```

I'd like for store creation to be taken care of within the module setup().

```
...
module("Unit - ActivitiesRoute", {
  setup: function(){
    var container = isolatedContainer([
      'route:activities'
    ]);

    route = container.lookup('route:activities');

    var store = {
       find: function(type){
         return new Em.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve){
            resolve(['activity', 'activity2', 'activity3']);  // or made up model(s) here
          });
       }
    };
    route.set('store', store);
  }
});
```

And the test:

```
test("#model", function(){
  deepEqual(route.model(), ['activity', 'activity2', 'activity3']); // ???
});
```

**Third approach:**

```
...
module('Unit - ActivitiesRoute', {
  setup: function() {
    var container = isolatedContainer([
      'route:activities'
    ]);

    route = container.lookup('route:activities');

    var store = {
      find: function() {

        var promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
          Em.run.later(function() {
            resolve(Activity.FIXTURES);
          }, 10);
        });

        return Ember.ArrayProxy.extend(Ember.PromiseProxyMixin).create({
          promise: promise
        });
      }
    };
    route.set('store', store);
  }
});
```

And in the test, calling route.model() returns an empty object {} :

```
test("#model", function(){
  deepEqual(route.model(), Activity.FIXTURES); // returns {}
});
```

### UPDATE #2

It was also necessary to add asyncTest() instead of test() and to also call start() to prevent the test runner from hanging.

```
asyncTest('#model', function(){
  Em.run(function(){
    route.model().then(function(result){
      ok(result);
      equal(result, Activity.FIXTURES);
      start();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple approach, it's a unit test, so really you aren't testing the store, so setup a mock store and result.

```
route = container.lookup('route:activities');
var store = {
   find: function(type){
      equal(type, 'activity', 'type is activity');
      return ['activity', 'activity2', 'activity3'];
   }
}

route.set('store', store);
```

Even better you can also replicate the promise

```
route = container.lookup('route:activities');
var store = {
   find: function(type){
      equal(type, 'activity', 'type is activity');
      return new Em.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve){
        resolve(['activity', 'activity2', 'activity3']);  // or made up model(s) here
      });
   }
}

route.set('store', store);
```

If you want to more closely replicate Ember Data you might use an ArrayProxy implementing the PromiseProxyMixin...

```
route = container.lookup('route:activities');
var store = {
   find: function(type){
      equal(type, 'activity', 'type is activity');
      var promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve){
        Em.run.later(function(){
          resolve(['activity', 'activity2', 'activity3']);
        }, 10);
      });

      return Ember.ArrayProxy.extend(Ember.PromiseProxyMixin).create({
        promise: promise
      });
   }
}

route.set('store', store);
```

### Update

Using your last approach you should implement it like this

```
test("#model", function(){
  route.model().then(function(result){
    deepEqual(result, Activity.FIXTURES); // returns {}
  });
});
```

But, there is something tricky here, since it has an async response you'll want to wrap it in an Ember run loop

```
test("#model", function(){
  Em.run(function(){
    route.model().then(function(result){
      deepEqual(result, Activity.FIXTURES); // returns {}
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: After looking closer here, I get the promise returned, but the array is assigned to _detail property, when using the second approach without PromiseProxyMixin.

Comment: I've updated the original question with some additional findings.

Comment: When something returns a promise you need to use a then to access the value, `promise.then(function(result){  //result in here is the result of the promise});`

Comment: whoops, I added that comment post seeing your comment, check out my updated answer at the bottom.

Comment: Not sure if there was a cleaner way, but I had to add asyncTest() instead of test() and to also call start() to prevent the test runner from hanging. Im looking at QunitAdapter and asyncEnd and wondering if there is a better way with ember-testing.

Comment: It would be helpful if your answer was a complete answer (as in, including `container` etc. above)

Comment: container is part of the question, if someone skips the question and just reads the answer context will always be poor.